# Is Ubuntu recognizing and/or using my NVIDIA graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 13.10, settings

This is my first post here, and I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux. I currently have no other OS except for Ubuntu 13.10. (I used to have Windows 7 until i got a new Tera-byte hard drive).

My current PC build, if any of this helps:

CPU: Intel i5 quad-core
Graphics: **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650**
RAM: 8 GB
HDD: 1 TB SATA 3
Motherboard: MSi Z77 A-G41
OS: Ubuntu 13.10

So I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and put Steam on it, and I'm seeing that my games run a lot slower than they did when I had Windows 7. I figured it was a graphics problem, so I checked System Settings → Details → Overview. It says in "Graphics" that I have "**Gallium 0.4 on NVE7**" (don't really know what that is). Does this mean that Ubuntu is not using my graphics card?

In System Settings → Software & Updates → Additional Drivers, it clearly shows like this:

> NVIDIA Corporation: GK107 [GeForce GTX 650]
>   -This device is using an alternative driver

(And then it shows a list of drivers that I can switch back and forth to)

So this is a bit confusing. In Software and Updates, it clearly shows that I have my NVIDIA card installed, and that I have a driver selected for it. But in System Settings, it shows I have some Gallium 0.4 thing.

I had done a bit of research, and ended up typing command:

```
lspci|grep VGA
```

in the Terminal. It showed this in response:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1)
```

The Terminal seems to recognize my graphics card.

What it looks like to me, is that I don't have the proper driver, and I might be using my CPU's integrated graphics. When I switch around which driver I am using in that list, it still does not see my card in System Settings. Some of the drivers in the list give me some sort of OpenGL error when I try to run a game.

It might just be that my games are running slow because the game developers have not optimized it for Ubuntu that well. However, that still doesn't take away from the fact that System Settings is not showing my NVIDIA card.

**TL;DR Version:**

How do I know if my video card is being recognized/used? If my video card is not being used, what is the best way fix that?

Please make your answers easy to understand. I do not mind wordy responses, as long as I can follow what you're saying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I using the Nouveau driver or the proprietary NVIDIA driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271613/am-i-using-the-nouveau-driver-or-the-proprietary-nvidia-driver)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card)

Answer (score 4):

- It seems you are running *free driver* where Steam recommend *NVIDIA proprietary driver*.
  You can confirm using: `glxinfo` or more precisely:

  ```
  glxinfo | grep OpenGL
  ```
- Myself I have bad experience with installing *NVIDIA proprietary driver* from Ubuntu repository. so I would prefer downloading it from [NVIDIA website](http://www.geforce.com/drivers). Check your OS architecture 32bit or 64bit using **System Monitor** or by just running one of these commands:

  ```
  file /bin/ls    
  uname -a
  ```
- Drop shell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> , login

  ```
  cd to_directory_where_driver
  sudo su
  chmod +x driver_filename
  service lightdm stop
  ./driver_filename
  reboot
  ```

Read very well the installing messages as the default is not always what you want.

You should keep that driver installation file because it needed in case you want to revert or repair the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to 'SOFTWARE & UPDATES' check 'Additional Drivers' Tab, and install the newest Driver listed there. then reboot.

[LINK](http://itsfoss.com/install-additonal-drivers-in-ubuntu-13-04/)

To install the latest NVidia drivers look here:

[LINK 1](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html)

[LINK 2](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

I found these articles useful, and this:

[General Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)

Steam help:

[LINK 1](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/better-steam-for-linux-performance-with.html)

[LINK 2](http://apcmag.com/how-to-improve-gaming-performance-on-your-linux-machine.htm)

I personally do not use Steam in Unity, I found it quite system resource heavy. So I installed an alternative light weight GUI, such as Gnome, LUbuntu, XUbuntu,etc, and run Steam from there, I found it greatly improved performance.

[LINK](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-alternatives-unity-ubuntu-users-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install drivers for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 in Ubuntu.

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA970DS3P
Processor: AMD FX-4130 Quad-Core 3.8GHz Socket AM3+

1. Download the drivers file from NVIDIA website

   - http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76884/en-us  for x64 Operating System
   - http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76881/en-us for x32 Operating System
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo service lightdm stop
   sudo init 3
   ```

   Change to the downloaded driver directory and run:

   ```
   sudo sh downloaded_file.run
   sudo service lightdm start 
   sudo reboot
   ```

If the Ubuntu boot displays an error message at startup follow these
steps to resolve a conflict of drivers:

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. After the reboot open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   sudo init 3
   ```

   Change to the downloaded driver directory and run:

   ```
   sudo sh downloaded_file.run
   sudo service lightdm start 
   sudo reboot
   ```