# Graphic Driver and low fps in game.

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Ok, so here is the problem I am having.  I am runing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Specs: Processor AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 450 Processor × 3 
       Graphics Card: GTS 450 1g
       RAM: 4.0 g ddr3

When I go to details it says that my graphics is Gallium 0.4 on NVC3.  I am not sure why it is saying that. Also when I play League of Legends I only have 20 fps at the lowest settings when I was getting 50 plus running it on windows. Is there something that I am doing wrong? Please Help :)

Comment: Did you install the proprietary NVidia graphics drivers? If not, you are likely using the open source drivers which do not support all the features of the card, as the proprietary ones do. Installing the proprietary drivers should give you better performance.

Comment: ok when i go to other drivers under NVIDIA Corp: blah blah i get options for .... open source and proprietary.. there are multiple options for both.

Comment: @BlakeMcDaniel: looking at your question and the comment in reply to dobey, I'm downvoting your question. A bit more of an active attitude in doing basic research is required on AskUbuntu in order to keep the quality of questions and answers high.

Comment: lol ok hahahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to switch to the proprietary NVIDIA drivers for better performance; Gallium is the open-source drivers, which are reverse-engineered and may not fully utilize the card's full capabilities. To do this, you can follow steps to install the proprietary drivers either through [Additional Drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) or by following steps similar to those in [Is Ubuntu recognizing and/or using my NVIDIA graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373214/is-ubuntu-recognizing-and-or-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card?rq=1)