# How to find the nouveau version used or installed into linux system (ubuntu v21.04)?

Tags: nouveau

How to find the nouveau version used or installed into linux system (ubuntu v21.04)?

I read a lot information [eg. here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271613/am-i-using-the-nouveau-driver-or-the-proprietary-nvidia-driver). However, none of the info found presenting the version of xorg / nouveau drivers. For an unknown reason, information is presenting only nvidia drivers version and not that of nouveau drivers.

So, what is the proper way to see what version of nouveau drivers are used by system?

Comment: The "user space" nouveau driver(s) : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so` from the  mesa package `libgl1-mesa-dri`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute-updates/amd64/libgl1-mesa-dri/filelist .... ( and nouveau_vieux_dri.so ).

Comment: "Tricks" to find files, 1. `locate nouveau` ........ 2. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=nouveau_dri.so&searchon=contents ...... (Version __ libgl1-mesa-dri (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3) ).

Comment: I have installed nouveau drivers using sudo apt install but also from source. So, I dont know which of two system use. Locate presents which results? nouveau drivers installled or used by system?

Comment: When you install the OS, Ubuntu 21.04, nouveau drivers are set by default. Unless you choose "Install 3rd party drivers".

Comment: This is not an answer to the very specific question.

Comment: Please guys, if you dont know the answer, dont post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be what you want to look for:

> `sudo dpkg -l *nouveau*`

the one with ii in front is the installed one.

Comment: `ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64      2.4.109+git2201210500.7aede9~oibaf~h amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:i386       2.4.109+git2201210500.7aede9~oibaf~h i386         Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  nouveau-firmware           20091212-0ubuntu1                    all          Firmware for nVidia graphics cards
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 1:1.0.17-1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver`
So the system uses all these versions?

Comment: Yes, seems like you have nouveau-firmware 32 and 64 bit  installed